# Was bedeutet genau "im Auftrag" (i.A.)?

Tags: abbreviation, letter

Manchmal bekomme ich Emails, in den so etwas als Unterschrift gilt:

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>
> Im Auftrag
>
> Herr Müller

Aber die Email-Adresse ist tatsächlich mueller@firma.com

Also bedeutet "im Auftrag" hier "Herr Müller hat im Auftrag seiner Firma geschrieben" oder "Ein Sekretär hat im Auftrag Herrn Müllers geschrieben"?

Falls es das letztere ist, wie soll ich das Email antworten? Noch "Sehr geehrter Herr Müller"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Den Brief hat Her Müller geschrieben. Deswegen solltest du ihn auch in deiner Antwort so anreden.

"[Im Auftrag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._A._(Abk%C3%BCrzung))" schreibt er darunter, um dir zu sagen, dass er *bevollmächtigt ist*, diesen Brief zu unterschreiben, und zwar nicht aufgrund seiner Position, sondern auf Grund des **Auftrags** (den ihm z.B. sein Chef gegeben hat, der damit seine Verantwortung delegiert hat).

Rein juristisch ist das Ganze etwas komplizierter, der verlinkte Wikipedia-Eintrag erklärt das aber ganz gut.

Comment: In der Praxis, scheint mir, ist das oft ein Formalismus geworden, über den Leute gar nicht mehr nachdenken. Sie verwenden ihn einfach "weil es so üblich ist".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Früher hat man druntergeschrieben "nach Diktat verreist, gez. Müller, Geschäftsführer", die Sekretärin mit "i.A." unterschreiben lassen, und im Prinzip dasselbe gemeint. Das ist z.B. "gar nicht mehr üblich". "Üblich" ist 'i.A.' nicht unbedingt, das ist schon ein bißchen mehr. Es ist die Angabe, mit welcher Legitimation der Absender eigentlich berechtigt ist, eine rechtsverbindliche Aussage zu tätigen.

Comment: Ja, aber es treibt auch eigentümliche Blüten. So versendet z.B. die Volkshochschule Hannover Briefe an ihre Kursteilnehmer (z.b. zur Bestätigung einer Anmeldung), die unterschrieben sind: "Mit freundlichen Grüßen, Der Oberbürgermeister", obwohl dieser natürlich den Brief nicht geschrieben hat und gar nichts von ihm weiß. Vielmehr hat eine Mitarbeiterin der VHS den Brief geschrieben. - Die ahnungslosen Empfänger erschrecken dann regelmäßig zu Tode, denn mit so einer Unterschrift sieht so ein Brief natürlich hochwichtig und rechtsfolgenbeladen aus.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann komm mal mit dem Auto nach Berlin und handle Dir dann hier einen Strafzettel ein - dann bekommst Du Post vom Polizeipräsidenten (wobei es dabei allerdings nicht um ein i.A. handelt, sondern um den Namen der gesamten Behörde: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Polizeipr%C3%A4sident_in_Berlin )

Comment: Mir hat meine VHS mal einen Mahnbescheid über 5 Euro geschickt. Furchtbar! Ich wollte danach irgendwie nichts mehr mit denen zu tun haben.